# TypeError: cannot subtract DatetimeArray from ndarray when prepending a row to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"start": [pd.to_datetime("2001-01-01 08:00:00+00:00")]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame([np.nan], columns=df.columns)
df1[["start"]] = [
    df["start"].iloc[0],
]
df = df1.append(df, ignore_index=True)

df["start"] - df["start"].dt.normalize()
```

produces the error

```
TypeError: cannot subtract DatetimeArray from ndarray
```

If I instead construct `df1` directly

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"start": [pd.to_datetime("2001-01-01 08:00:00+00:00")]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame([df["start"].iloc[0],], columns=df.columns)
df = df1.append(df, ignore_index=True)

df["start"] - df["start"].dt.normalize()
```

I don't get an error. I am wondering what is the problem with the first approach?